# Why weakening a precondition does not violate Liskov substitution principle

Tags: oop, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I am learning about LSP in detail and I do understand why strenghtening preconditions violates the principle (using the example from http://www.ckode.dk/programming/solid-principles-part-3-liskovs-substitution-principle/#contravariance):

```
public class SuperType  
{  
    public virtual string FormatName(string name)  
    {  
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))  
            throw new ArgumentException("name cannot be null or empty", "name");  
        return name;  
    }  
}  

//VIOLATING ONE
public class LSPIllegalSubType : SuperType  
{  
    public override string FormatName(string name)  
    {  
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || name.Length < 4)  
            throw new ArgumentException("name must be at least 4 characters long", "name");  
        return name;  
    }  
}
```

Here I clearly can see that what would be valid for the base class would fail for its derivative. In other words, I would not be able to replace the base class with its derivative without changing the behavior.

Now the following method is considered legal, as it weakens the preconditions:

```
    public class LSPLegalSubType : SuperType  
{  
    public override string FormatName(string name)  
    {  
        if (name == null)  
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");  
        return name;  
    }  
}
```

Quoting the site: this is perfectly legal as any valid arguments to the supertype will also be valid in the subtype.

Well, but what about invalid arguments? If I have a code that calls the SuperType with invalid arguments (e.g. empty name), it fails. If I replace it with a subtype, the same call will not fail because the condition is weaker. So in that sense, I cannot replace the supertype with subtype as it would change the behavior too. I am puzzled.

Comment: Your second example strengthens the precondition.

Comment: Ah, sorry, wrong code snippet! You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you weaken a precondition, the subtype is still compatible with places expecting the supertype.  It may not throw an exception where the base class does normally, but that is okay, because throwing less exceptions should not break the consuming code.  If the calling code is built around the assumption that exceptions get thrown in certain places, and uses that for primary control flow of the application, the consuming code should probably be rewritten.

Also, I think your second code sample is wrong.

If the preconditions of the base class really must be enforced all the time, a better implementation would be to create a data type that encapsulates those rules, and pass that as a parameter.  That way it is not in the hand of subclasses, it is part of the new class's constructor.

Ex:

```
public class UserName 
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public UserName(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value) || value.Length < 4)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

        Value = value;
    }
}

public class BaseClass 
{
    public virtual void Foo(UserName username) 
    { 
        //No precondition checks required here 
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Foo(UserName username) 
    {
        //No precondition checks required here
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I placed the right code snippet from the example. But I still do not get it - if I replace the base class with its derivative and the behaviour changes (as in the example), how is that still OK? Like in the example - empty string is not allowed by the base class, but OK for the derivative, which weakens that to a string not being null.

Comment: This is kind of a problem with the general exception throwing pattern in .NET and similar systems.  Thrown exceptions are not part of the public interfaces of types, and so these contracts are hard to enforce at compile time.  From outside the `SuperType` class, there is no clear way to know what preconditions it has.  By making a `Username` type, you can make the type system enforce these contracts.  LSP doesn't really consider the case of breaking from weakened preconditions, but its possible. Maybe another side to LSP is to not design your classes so subclasses can break them.

Comment: Well I think it does not relate to exceptions specifically. Let's say the base class performs a function when A,B,C are true, while its derivative does the same when only A is true.

Comment: Very true.  It's not about exceptions specifically.  A big part of SOLID generally is, when consuming a class, don't make any assumptions about anything that is not part of its public interface.  This includes thrown exceptions, side effects you know happen from looking at private members, etc. Pretend you cannot see the source code of that class when consuming it.

Comment: So I am still confused. If I call the method in the base class with null name, I get the exception. If I substitute it with the subtype, it will work. I cannot wrap my head around why that is OK? Maybe because when providing the subtype, I should expect that it might accept more than the supertype?

Comment: The one-way aspect is about _Covariance_ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/ Variables in C# and similar languages are Covariant.  So if you have a variable of type `SuperType`, it can hold values of `SubType`, but you cannot treat them as anything more specific.  You cannot assign values to variables in the opposite way (_Contravariant_). So if a 3rd party lib has a method with a param of type `SuperType` and at runtime you pass it a `SubType` instance, new exceptions that that class was not designed to catch will not be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

A method with pre and postconditions is stating that when the precondition is satisfied by the caller, then it guarentees the postconditions will be satisfied on exit. However, the contract does not state what will happen if the precondition is *not* satisfied - it is still permitted for the method to complete successfully. Therefore subtypes can weaken the precondition, since callers cannot make any assumptions on the behaviour of a method if they fail to satisfy the subtype's precondition.

Comment: What do you mean? If the precondition is not met, then the execution should not happen.

Comment: @user970696 - That is usually what will happen, but from the caller's point of view cannot be relied on. Callers are responsible for satisfying the base type's preconditions, which they will always do if subtypes avoid strengthening them.